# WireGuard VPN Default Route Ignoring LAN

Tags: network, vpn

I have a WireGuard VPN setup on my MacBook Pro (macOS 11.5.2) to connect to my home network and proxy some external traffic while I'm away.

Currently, the VPN will not allow routes on the same subnet as my local LAN (`192.168.1.0/24`), despite having `0.0.0.0/0` entered as `AllowedIPs`. This same configuration works flawlessly on my other Linux machines.

`netstat -rn` shows the `default` WireGuard interface above the `default` WiFi interface with the LAN gateway of `192.168.1.1`. What am I missing?